# Fixtures data for model containing images, files and tags

Tags: django, django-models, django-taggit, django-fixtures, easy-thumbnails

I am using Djano 3.1, Python 3.6, easy-thumbnails 2.7 and django-taggit 1.3

I want to create a fixtures data file for my model.

Here is my (simplified) model:

#### myapp/models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    featured_image = ThumbnailerImageField(upload_to='uploads/post/featured_image', blank=True, null=True) 
    content = models.CharField(max_text=1000, null=False, blank=False)
    tags = TaggableManager()
    

class PostFileAttachment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='attachments', on_delete = mFixtures data for model containing images and filesodels.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="uploads/post/attachments") 


class PostImageGallery(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='pictures', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, default='')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/blogpost/gallery')
```

#### myapp/fixtures/sample_data.json

```
[
    {
      "model": "myapp.Post",
      "pk": 1,
      "fields": {
        "featured_image": ???
        "content": "This is where the content goes"
        "tags": ???
      }
    },
    {
      "model": "myapp.PostFileAttachment",
      "pk": 1,
      "fields": {
          "post": 1
          "file": ???
      }
    },
    {
      "model": "myapp.PostImageGallery",
      "pk": 1,
      "fields": {
         "post": 1
         "description": "File description",
         "image": ???
      }
    }
]
```

How do I specify files in my JSON fixtures file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you try via `admin` interface to save a `Post` with an image e.g `image.png` and then you look the database, you will find that the post's image was saved with its relative path : `uploads/post/featured_image/image.png`,  so in your fixture you need to specify that path.

in your `myapp/fixtures/sample_data.json` fixture file it should be like

```
[
    {
      "model": "myapp.Post",
      "pk": 1,
      "fields": {
        "featured_image": "uploads/post/featured_image/FEATURED_IMAGE.EXT",
        "content": "This is where the content goes",
      }
    },
    {
      "model": "myapp.PostFileAttachment",
      "pk": 1,
      "fields": {
          "post": 1,
          "file": "uploads/post/attachments/ATTACHMENT.EXT",
      }
    },
    {
      "model": "myapp.PostImageGallery",
      "pk": 1,
      "fields": {
         "post": 1,
         "description": "File description",
         "image": "uploads/blogpost/gallery/IMAGE.EXT",
      }
    }
]
```

Comment: This just loads the string of the filename to the database

Comment: fixtures are intended to pre-populate database (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/initial-data/) and files can be then moved manully or even better with a custom command.

Comment: have a look at this package it maybe useful https://pypi.org/project/django-media-fixtures/